# express api (or server render) with three.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, typescript, three.js

I want to generate 3d models in base64 format (or any type of image) to use statically, but there is a problem: the only way I found it was with three.js, and my application is a web application that runs on a server (node.js), there is no page to load three.js. I can't find solutions to generate static images of a 3d model server-side to save and re-use.

to be more clear, I want to generate a minecraft skin (in model, character format) from the image.png skin. and I've already had success doing this with an [HTML page](https://azazel.onrender.com/starpiece/editskin/NjkxNzI2OTE2), but I have no idea how to do this on the server side.
I know that there is a way for me to use three.js with nodejs (without `three/examples/jsm/..`, and there is a lib for that), but the tools always give some conflict. I can't use "modules" in the typescript application, which forces me to find a solution myself (since the html solution is a module). The code that I run in HTML is not possible to be used in NodeJs, mainly because the main tool (SkinViewer3D) is made to run in HTML.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Until then, I just generated an [HTML page](https://azazel.onrender.com/starpiece/editskin/NjkxNzI2OTE2) that does what I want, but this is not useful enough, as the user needs to open the page to load the model and I can save a copy of the model in static form. What I want is to be able to generate the model and a print of it without having to open an HTML page.

Initially I thought of a way to use this with a rest api that returns a base64 of the ready model, receiving a parameter (skin url) and rendering it on the server, then returning the printout of the customized and rendered model. but I also don't know how I can do this, since I use express, and this is **nodejs** (and I don't want to use puppeter to load the entire page and then export).

my second option is to have a method/class already within the application, which will load the 3d model and then return a print of it to be used statically, which I even prefer, but still, it's within nodejs.

Comment: I want to avoid using interfaces as much as possible, mainly because everything will run inside a docker.

Comment: Since you don't have to run in the browser, why limit yourself to webgl and three.js? You could have a raytracer rendering this in rust, endless possibilities.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.